# facebook login status without APP access

Tags: javascript, php

Ok, I know about FB.getLoginStatus, but this is different

FB.getLoginStatus is working to access the APP to see if the user is login or not

And I really don't want that.

I just need to determine if my visitor is logged to facebook, if yes then what is the fb username?

Is there is something like what I need?

Comment: no, it is against security rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done, to get any information from a Facebook user they have to allow your app to do so.